# How to remove words after certain character in a line in python

Tags: python

I am trying to delete comments from a file, the comments start with "#" symbol. I am able to remove comments that starts the line with '#' but there are some comments in the file that are starting in between the line. Is there any method to remove comments like that.?

Here is the sample code.

```
# modified code
begin
 stuff
 stuff
end # ended module
```

I want to delete the text followed by # in line 5.

Comment: What did you try to solve this problem?

Comment: Loop over each line and `split('#')[0]` .  Assuming you don't have any `#` inside strings of course.